# MultiView with a GridView has a row with a DropDownList where the SelectedIndexChanged event doesn't update second DropDownList

Tags: .net, gridview, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged, multiview

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find this exact permutation previously posted.  The similar solutions didn't actually solve my problem.

So I've got a Multiview, with a Gridview in one of the views.  A row of the grid contains separate DropDownLists, the changing of grid A updates the selections that should appear in grid B.  And the update doesn't happen.  The gist of the code is as follows:

```
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server">
    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
         DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"
         OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlA"
                         OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlA_SelectedIndexChanged"
                         runat="server"/>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlB" runat="server" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

And the code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                MyCustomObject myObject = (MyCustomObject)e.Row.DataItem;
                PopulateObjectRow(myObject, e.Row);
            }
        }
}

protected void ddlA_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList sender = (DropDownList)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)sender.NamingContainer;
    MyCustomObject myObject = (MyCustomObject)e.Row.DataItem;
    myObject.FirstSelection = sender.SelectedItem.Value;
    PopulateObjectRow(row, sender.SelectedItem.Value);
}

private void PopulateObjectRow(MyCustomObject myObject, GridViewRow row)
{
    DropDownList ddlA = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlA");
    ddlA.SelectedItem = GetSelectionItems();
    ddlA.DataBind();
    if(myObject.FirstSelection.IsValid())
    {
        SetSelection(ddlA, myObject.FirstSelection);
    }

    DropDownList ddlB = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlB");
    ddlB.DataSource = GetDataValues(ddlA.SelectedItem.Value);
    ddlB.DataBind();
}
```

Now the hell of it is, that as I debug the code and walk through it, ddlB.DataSource has the expected values in it.  It just looks like the ddlB.DataBind() event isn't actually doing anything.  Is GridView.OnRowDataBound() too late to effect this change?  As an added headache, this all works just fine as a stand alone GridView.  It's only when I wrap it in the MultiView that it stops functioning!  My assumption is that I'm doing something out of sequence here, but I'll be damned if I can find it...

Comment: I don't know the answer to your problem but your question helped me solve a problem I was having so +1 to you.